# How to fix air valve in apartment

Tags: heating, valve

There is an air valve in my pre-war apartment that from time to time will blow air out really loudly. Sometimes the air is hot, sometimes it is cool, but it gets really loud, and has been interrupting my sleep constantly for the past week. I'm not 100% sure on what exactly it is, but I'm fairly certain its just an air valve that's somehow connected to the heating of the building.

I am trying to figure out a DIY solution to this, and was considering just duct taping over the valve openings, but because the air sometimes gets hot, was worried about the potential case of fire. What other solutions could I explore?

[Video to short clip showing the valve and noise](https://upload-video.net/a11067VG211-noau)

Comment: Looks like a steam valve. Don't block it.

Comment: How can I either make the sound softer or stop the sound outright?

Comment: The proper way to fix this is to complain to whoever manages the heat in your building. Unfortunately, I don't expect them to fix this. This is a sign of putting out too much steam, but unless it's real bad, they're probably going to say that this is just how the system works.

Comment: I take it your building has steam heat, then?

Comment: Yes, there is heat coming out of this valve, and then I have radiators in other rooms.

Comment: What is directly above that valve?

Comment: There's nothing above the valve apart from the ceiling... I'm not sure what you mean.